# How to store results of an iteration in a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, iteration

For educational reasons,  I am working through a simple algorithm that randomly generates two numbers and then asks for the addition of generated numbers, tells you if you are right or wrong on response, and tracks results out of 100.  I would like to include function that reports something like the following:  "You have gotten 80/100 correct"  But am held up with syntax, I think.  I can't get my score variable to count up with correct answers.

Here is my code as it stands..

```
do{

var firstnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
var secondnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
var result = firstnum+secondnum;
var score=0;


var answer = prompt("what is "+firstnum + "+" + secondnum);

if(answer < result || answer > result){alert("Wrong! " + "The correct answer 
is " + result)};

if(answer == result){alert("you are correct!"), score++};


alert("Awesome, You have gotten " + score + " correct so far!!!");}
while(score<100);
```

Just get me over the hump.  I am hopeful that I can really get my head wrapped around more concepts if I can get through this little guy.

Comment: declare & initialize variable outside loop

Comment: As you are learning, I propose the following challenges: "When the user does not provide an answer, ask if they would like to quit" (current loop never stops unless the user gets 100 correct), "Show only 1 alert/prompt per round" (i.e. current loop has 2 alerts and a prompt, condense this to just one), "After 5 correct answers in a row, ask the user if they'd like to up the difficulty"

Comment: Challenges accepted. Thanks for the input.  Variables to top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reset `score` in every loop to zero. Move the declaration and initialization to top.

Some hints:

- no need for semicolons after a [block statement `{ /* code */ }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block),
- convertion of strinn to number with [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus)
- use a single [`if` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) with `else` block for the opposite of the check.

```js
// declare all variables at top
var firstnum,
    secondnum,
    result,
    score = 0,
    answer;

do {
    firstnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    secondnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    result = firstnum + secondnum;
    // covert input string to number with unary plus
    answer = +prompt("what is " + firstnum + "+" + secondnum);
    //       ^

    // just check the result and omit a second if clause,
    // because it is just the opposite check
    // take the more easy/shorter check first
    if (answer === result ) {
        alert("you are correct!");
        score++;
    } else {
        alert("Wrong! " + "The correct answer is " + result)
    }
    alert("Awesome, You have gotten " + score + " correct so far!!!");
} while (score < 2) // take a small number for scoring check
```

Comment: I'd argue it would be better to use the unary plus on `answer` when comparing it to `result` and check if the user has actually responded to the prompt first.

Comment: Eureka!  The variables outside the loop will store the value instead of resetting it.  I knew it was something like that, but was unable to "click" in my head.